# sending message to a Handler on a dead thread Run-time Exception in Android while receiving message from GCM

Tags: android, user-interface, media-player, google-cloud-messaging

> I'm trying to Play audio file using MediaPlayer, and am getting a
>   RunTime Exception "sending message to a Handler on a dead thread". The
>   class that is trying to show the extends IntentService. Here is the
>   method

```
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
Handler mHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.whistle);
                    mp.setLooping(false);
                    mp.start();
                    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            mp.release();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: no answers?! having the same issue here. You should specify that you are playing the sound from a Service

Comment: @ChetakBhimani Have you find solution for this?